# How to search with LIKE in columns merged with AS

Tags: php, sql, sql-like

I merged two column with AS , now I want to search data inside them with LIKE. How can i do that? Here is what I have tries so far.

Php :

```
$sql = "SELECT CONCAT (name , ' ' , surname) AS full  FROM person ";
$query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if($query){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        echo "<p>$row[full]</p>";
    }
}else{
    echo mysqli_error($con);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could try like this - using the `having` clause rather than where

```
select concat( field1, field2 ) as 'alias'
from `table`
having `alias` like '%word%'
```

or, in your case:

```
SELECT CONCAT (`name` , ' ' , `surname`) AS 'full'  FROM `person`
having `full` like '%word%';
```

Comment: Yes . exactly as I want . I changed a little : concat( field1, ' ' , field2 )

Answer (score 0):

Use subquery.

Subquery `"SELECT CONCAT (name , ' ' , surname) AS full  FROM person "`

Complete Query :

```
SELECT * from (SELECT CONCAT (name , ' ' , surname) AS full  FROM person) where 
full like '%a%';
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: I received an error = "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Comment: Try this   SELECT b.* from (SELECT CONCAT (name , ' ' , surname) AS full  FROM person)b  where 
b.full like '%a%';

Answer (score 0):

You can try also

```
SELECT * 
FROM pages 
WHERE CONCAT_WS('', column1, column2, column3) LIKE '%keyword%'
```

Comment: PHP 'while' how I wrote ?